# Jenkins - call rest api via token

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to call a Jenkins API using

```
curl -X GET -L --user [USERID]:[API_TOKEN] http://JENKINS-HOST/job/JOB/api/json?tree=allBuilds[description,result]
```

but I am getting Access Denied message
Message
Access Denied

```
USERID is missing the Overall/Read permission
```

USERID and API_TOKEN I had taken from my profile configure area. From Jenkins, I can visit this URL, but with rest call, it is not working. What else I am missing??

I am using SSO to login to Jenkins

Comment: Try this out `curl -X GET -L --user “[USERID]:[API_TOKEN]” “http://JENKINS-HOST/job/JOB/api/json?tree=allBuilds[description,result]”`

Comment: It is not working and giving same response

Comment: did you try user:password mechanism(for debugging)?  What is the SSO configured?   Do you have access to Jenkins log? it may have   more details?